# Bootstrap not importing correctly via node module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm having issues importing bootstrap for my angular2 app.
I have it as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>


<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In my app.component.html file I have

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
```

But the button never turns green and I don't get an import error for the css file, but the console says 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for the js file import.

Any help is appreciated

file structure image

[image]

[image]

Response Tab

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>


<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Additional File Structure image
[image]

```
General 

    Request URL:http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:304 Not Modified
    Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200

    Response Headers
    view source
    Accept-Ranges:bytes
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Connection:keep-alive
    Date:Sat, 24 Dec 2016 20:33:37 GMT
    ETag:W/"27f-NL3AUEhbYCYcjueARo/8Ow"
    X-Powered-By:Express

    Request Headers
    view source
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:localhost:4200
    If-None-Match:W/"27f-NL3AUEhbYCYcjueARo/8Ow"
    Referer:http://localhost:4200/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you check your network tab to see if you are getting the correct bootstrap files? Press F12 while chrome browser is open -> select the network tab -> refresh the browser -> search for your bootstrap files.

Comment: Can't you just do it by npm?

Comment: when I hit f12 and go to network > css/js tab and refresh the .js and .css bootstrap files are listed. Why aren't they kicking in to turn button green? Also In response to K. Daniek. I didn't know you could import using npm. How would that be done?

Comment: @user6680 when you click on the bootstrap related files in the network, on the right panes response tab, do you see the related content? or do you see your index.html?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see a response tab. I added an image above showing the list of files in the all tab. index.html isn't within that list if you scroll down. If that is what your asking

Comment: @user6680 click on the bootstrap.js it should open that requests details. What are you getting in response to your bootstrap.js request?

Comment: Oh ok. I added the code under the response tab at the bottom of my post. It looks like my index.html file

Comment: @user6680 just as I suspected :) you are not successfully importing the bootstrap files. Can you confirm that `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` and the css file exists?

Comment: It does exist though. Look at first image of file structure and then I just added another to show bootstrap directory. You should be able to see all the directories between the two images

Comment: @user6680 Can you also check the request url of bootstrap files in the network tab? That's in the headers tab, something like: `http:localhost:port/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`

Comment: I added it to post above

Comment: @user6680 What I just realized is that your node_modules folder is one level above your index.html so your import should be `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` but I don't think that's gonna work since the base href is index.html. You should move your node_modules to the same dir level as your index.html

Answer (score 2):

This solution will make it work if using SystemJs(if you use webpack dont do step 4) :

1-Install via npm:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

2-Import:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

3-List the imported module in your application module:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
      imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],  
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }
```

4-Add to `system.config.js` file :

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'  // -> as in angular2 main tutorial, npm is set to replace havin to write node_modules
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
         ...
         //ng-bootstrap
         '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
        }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I am new with it, but I have this line that I link to the html.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I know that I can import bootstrap via cdn, but I'm trying to import a local bootstrap file via npm/node module

Answer (score 0):

Your `node_modules` folder is one level above your `index.html` so your import should be `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`

However, I don't think that's going to work either because the base href to angular2 projects are usually the `index.html`. You should move your `node_modules` folder to the same dir level as your `index.html`.

Comment: Is this not the proper way to import files? Moving the node_modules file seems not right if I'm installing packages using npm. Is the proper way to do this if using npm to follow FRECIA method below? I don't understand why I can't point to the file path using ../node_modules etc... exactly where npm puts the files to begin with

Comment: @user6680 If you check the angular2 seed index.html and the package.json are in the same level https://github.com/angular/quickstart. If you are worried about your back-end (if you are using something like node.js), you can create another package.json for your back-end at that level.

Comment: @user6680 Even if you give the refs like FRECIA I don't think systemjs can resolve a path that is one level above it. Feel free to try and let me know :)

Comment: @user6680 any news?